# How to get base corresponding code through github compare url?

Tags: git, github, git-reset

I get a github compare url from BugSwarm (a bug dataset), like this one:

```
https://github.com/apache/dubbo/compare/0c438dc4889517bf9924a49aeb3c5562c1b96944..36ae90cab1aee74658dc8bdd5d785fd79fd0fe2c
```

I assumed the base commit hash was "0c438dc4889517bf9924a49aeb3c5562c1b96944", but when I use `git reset --hard 0c438dc4889517bf9924a49aeb3c5562c1b96944` in all five branches of dubbo repo. It turns out

```
fatal: Could not parse object '0c438dc4889517bf9924a49aeb3c5562c1b96944'.
```

It seems the commit hash does not exist. I want to checkout the code correponding to the compare url base to get bug information. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: If that commit hash works on GitHub, it exists in the repository *on GitHub*. It may not exist in some other repository, such as your own clone. If so, you can get the commit from GitHub, using `git fetch`. Depending on your own repository's Git configuration and what's going on on GitHub, you might get with an ordinary, simple `git fetch origin`, or you might have to do something fancy.

Comment: Oh, I already tried `git fetch`, but I failed.

Comment: Did you just run `git fetch origin`? (Is `origin` = `https://github.com/apache/dubbo`?) If so, try `git fetch origin 0c438dc4889517bf9924a49aeb3c5562c1b96944:refs/heads/tmp` to create a branch named `tmp` whose tip commit is the one you're looking for. (It's actually in some fork, as you can see at https://github.com/apache/dubbo/commit/0c438dc4889517bf9924a49aeb3c5562c1b96944)

Comment: If `origin` isn't that URL, you may need to add a remote with that URL, or fetch directly from that URL; you may want to add `--no-tags` to your `git fetch`.